# Azure Search using Lucene Query Syntax Returns Incorrect Results

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am using the Microsoft.Azure.Search .NET SDK v5.0.1.  I am attempting to perform a search against my Azure Search index as follows: Documents.SearchAsync("fieldname:val* AND timeStamp:2018-05-03T13\:23\:59Z").  The results are incorrect.  There are exactly 2 documents in my index with that timestamp.  There are 121 documents in my index where the fieldname starts with val.  When I run the above query using the SDK, it always returns 121 documents.  Is there some special way to query timestamp that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few points to make here:

1. In your index definition, I believe you have `timeStamp` set to be a String. Otherwise you wouldn't have been able to make the search query as DateTime fields are not searchable. Firstly, I'd advice against treating `timeStamp` as a string. This is because searchable fields go through a bunch of analysis (tokenization being one of them) [Reference on query parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture). In your case, the `timestamp` query (say `2018-05-03`) will be tokenized into smaller constituents (2018, 05, 03) and documents containing any of those terms will be returned. Which is why you observe what you see.
2. Your scenario seems to be a classic case of "filter" results based on a criteria, followed by "search" on the filtered documents. To accomplish this, you need to do the following:

   - Use a filter on the timestamp, so that it doesn't go through the analysis
   - On the filtered results, apply your search query.
   - [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-dotnet-sdk)
3. I strongly recommend however that if possible, you should make your `timeStamp` column a datetime for more reasonable semantics.

As an example, here's how you'd go about achieving a filter + search combo:

```
parameters = new SearchParameters() 
{
   Filter = "timeStamp eq '2018-05-03'"
};
Documents.SearchAsync("fieldname:val*", parameters);
```

Comment: Thank you.  Your answer was what I was afraid of.  For internal reasons, it is going to be very difficult for us to combine Filter and searchText.  However, I understand what you are saying.  I will mark this as the answer because it is.  I'll play with modifying the timeStamp type (you are correct; it is a string).

Comment: I’m curious why it is difficult for you to combine searchText and filters. Is it because you sometimes need to OR such conditions together instead of AND them?